# Symfony2: Getting Exception while "How to create a custom Authentication Provider"

Tags: authentication, symfony, provider

i am new to Symfony2 and need to create a Custom Authentication Provider, so i read the [How to create a custom Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html).
I created all classes, also the Custom User Provider from [How to create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) but i am getting this Exception:

```
RuntimeException: The parent definition "wsse.security.authentication.provider" defined for definition "security.authentication.provider.wsse.wsse_secured" does not exist.
```

I copy/pasted all classes and configuration parts from the Cookbook and only changed my Bundlename.

Comment: For WSSE, you might want to look at https://github.com/mjhapp/MjhWsseBundle which is the Symfony2 cookbook article wrapped up in a bundle.

Comment: I tried to move the definition of the services to app/config/security.yml and it works. I dont know why its not working if i define them in the bundle/Resources/config/services.yml as the tutorial says.

Comment: Is your DIC loading your services.yml in your bundle?

Comment: Yeah actualy i didn't had the Bundle*Extension Class which loads my services.yml...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments above - for those having the same problem I think Reza Sanaie's answer not the intended solution. 
You should better check if you have a file */DependencieInjection/Security/{Vendor}{YourBundleName}Extension.php* in your Bundle. The file needs to have the correct filename and the class will be executed by symfony2 kernel automatically.
If you have a look into the class-code of this file you will see something like

```
$loader->load('services.yml');
```

This will load your services.yml and the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 5):

You need to update your config.yml to include in the services config from your bundle in your main application

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: @AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/services.yml }
```

Comment: OP should have accepted this as correct - nice quick answer that the manual is super vague about. Mentions using the correct import syntax,  but does not show what this correct syntax is; answer works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry, should have answered my question... i just mentioned it as a comment above. The right answer is below from chsymann or in a comment by me under the question. The problem was the missing _{YourBundleName}Extension.php_ file

Comment: Good call, that is definitely the correct answer if you left off the Extension class.